# How to bind a String to a TexBlock Property ? WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this :

```
TextBlock MyText = new TextBlock();
String SomeWords;
```

I want to bind those two properties but I dont know how to do it with a string :

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath(MyText.Text);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(SomeWords, ???????, binding);
```

What am I suppose to put at the emplacement of the question marks ?

Ty !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
TextBlock MyText = new TextBlock();

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Name"); //Name of the property in Datacontext
BindingOperations.SetBinding(MyText,TextBlock.TextProperty , binding);
```

If you want to bind to property of some other object you will need to set binding.Source to that object.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are technically more correct to this particular question given you are trying to create the binding in code, but usually people perform these simple bindings through xaml.

Xaml View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyTextPropertyFromViewModel}" />
```

C# ViewModel:

```
public String MyTextPropertyFromViewModel
{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be the target property of the binding, ie your `TextBlock.TextProperty`

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx